In a table with As and Bs, select those As for which the Bs are all associated with a given list of B_criteria
Given the following table structure:
Table A



a




1


2


3



Table AB



a
b




1
1


1
2


1
3


2
1


2
2


3
2


3
3



Table B



b




1


2


3



Problem description: Given a list of b's, I want to query those a's which are associated with ALL b's in AB.
Or formulated more generally, I want to retrieve all a's which match a given criteria list b. The length of the list of b's (i.e. the criteria count) can be anywhere from 1 to 20.
Example: Given a b list of (2, 3), I want to retrieve a's 1 and 3 because they are each associated with 2 and 3 in AB.
Question: The described problem sounds like a very generic problem which would come up often - is there a best solution on how to efficiently solve this query pattern in a relational database?
Is there a more optimal way to set up the table structure in order to answer this particular query pattern? What would be the best types of indices to use here?

My current approach
Currently I use the following approach, however I'm not sure if that's the best way most efficiently select the data.
I use B-tree indices on A(a), B(b), AB(a,b), AB(b,a).
Let's call the criteria list b_criteria=(b1, b2, ...), I query the data with:
SELECT DISTINCT ab.a
FROM AB ab
WHERE
  ab.b = `b_criteria[b_lowest_cardinality_index]`

AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM AB q WHERE ab.a = q.a AND q.b = `b_criteria[1]`)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM AB q WHERE ab.a = q.a AND q.b = `b_criteria[2]`)
...
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM AB q WHERE ab.a = q.a AND q.b = `b_criteria[n]`)


So I select a's which all match the EXISTS clause.
Additionally I try to already start with the lowest possible count of rows by preselecting only those rows with b=b_lowest_cardinality. I can choose b_lowest_cardinality beforehand, by counting how many count(b) grouped by b are in total in AB. The cardinalities of b differ strongly in AB (i.e. there might be many more b=3 in AB as b=2, for example).
Background info:
In my instance I have

A row count: 400 million
AB row count: 4 billion
B row count: 4000
Database: Oracle


Oracle or SQL Server? They are competing database products

I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?

Unfortunately your question is not specific enough. If you have a performance issue then post the execution plan for assistance.

I can't talk for Oracle, however, backticks (```) aren't a valid delimit identifier in T-SQL.

@ThomA I just spotted the last line of the question :)

Those backticks should just mark the places to insert the actual b numbers, e.g. the actual query is then AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM AB q WHERE ab.a = q.a AND q.b = 5), if b_criteria[1] = 5

I think this is called relation division. Usually, what you do is: select * from A where exists(select 1 from AB where AB.A = A.A AND AB.B IN (SELECT YOUR Bs here) HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT YOUR Bs here))) This usually get a bit more ugly if you can have duplicates :)

select distinct a from ab where b in (1, 2, 3) group by a having count(*) = 3 ?

You can use the below for your requirement as explained by you
 with data as (select 
    1 a, 1 b from dual union all 
    select 1,   2 from dual union all 
    select 1,   3 from dual union all 
    select 2,   1 from dual union all 
    select 2,   2 from dual union all 
    select 3,   2 from dual union all 
    select 3,   3 from dual)  
    select A from (select sum(1) over (partition by A ) sum1 ,a,b ,count(distinct b) over ()  count2 
      from data 
    where b in (2,3)
    ) 
      where sum1=count2
      group by A;


Since you have such a huge number of rows to process maybe you could try to do it using MODEL clause which, arguably quite often, is faster than other options dealing with large datasets.
WITH 
    Table_AB (A, B) AS
        ( Select 1, 1  From Dual Union All
          Select 1, 2  From Dual Union All
          Select 1, 3  From Dual Union All
          Select 2, 1  From Dual Union All
          Select 2, 2  From Dual Union All
          Select 3, 2  From Dual Union All
          Select 3, 3  From Dual 
        )
SELECT  A
FROM    ( Select  *
          From    ( Select  * From Table_AB )
              MODEL   Partition By ( A )
                      Dimension By ( B )
                      Measures ( 0 "CNT" )
              RULES ( CNT[ANY] = Count(*)[B IN(your B list here)] )  
        )
WHERE CNT = number_of_elements_in_B_list_here
GROUP BY A

/*      R e s u l t s :
For (2,3)2     For (1,2)2      For (1,2,3)3    **(B list)elements**
         A              A                 A
----------    -----------    -------------- 
         1              1                 1
         3              2                   */

ADDITION:
We don't know the code of your query that creates the B list to be processed. Here is one of the options to have such a query. A B_lists CTE below might be a source for different lists:
    B_lists (ID, LIST_ELEMENT) AS
        ( Select 101, 1 From Dual Union All
          Select 102, 1 From Dual Union All
          Select 102, 2 From Dual Union All
          Select 103, 2 From Dual Union All
          Select 103, 3 From Dual Union All
          Select 104, 1 From Dual Union All
          Select 104, 2 From Dual Union All
          Select 104, 3 From Dual 
        )

... the data from above could be used as a subquery within the MODEL
sql code using different lists depending on ID in the Where clause of subquery...
One option for subquery getting a list (for ID = 103) could be:
Select  Distinct ',' || LISTAGG(LIST_ELEMENT, ',') WITHIN GROUP (Order By LIST_ELEMENT) Over(Partition By ID) || ',' "B_LIST",
        Count(*) Over(Partition By ID) "B_COUNT"
From    B_lists 
Where   ID = 103
/* R e s u l t :
B_LIST  B_COUNT
------  -------
,2,3,         2   */

... using above subquery in the MODEL sql code (Inner Join) ...
SELECT  A
FROM    ( Select    *
          From      (  ( Select  * From Table_AB ) ab 
          Inner Join   ( Select  Distinct ',' || LISTAGG(LIST_ELEMENT, ',') WITHIN GROUP (Order By LIST_ELEMENT) Over(Partition By ID) || ',' "B_LIST",
                                            Count(*) Over(Partition By ID) "B_COUNT"
                                    From    B_lists 
                                    Where   ID = 103 ) l ON(1 = 1)
                    )
                          MODEL   Partition By ( A )
                                  Dimension By ( B )
                                  Measures ( B_LIST, B_COUNT, 0 "CNT" )
                          RULES ( CNT[ANY] = Count(*)[InStr(B_LIST[CV()], ',' || B || ',') > 0] )  
        )
WHERE CNT = B_COUNT
GROUP BY A

... results are the same as above for the same lists
/*      R e s u l t s :
For ID 103     For ID 102        For ID 104    **ID from B_lists CTE**
         A              A                 A
----------    -----------    -------------- 
         1              1                 1
         3              2                   */

NOTE: There are comma delimiters at the begining and end of the list for use with InStr() function testing the list elements. There are other ways to do it. This is just an example of one of the options. You should do the adjustments to your context yourself.

"your B list here" will not work because on the real dataset it would be a subquery which is not authorized here by the MODEL clause.

@p3consulting The query that defines the list could be joined to the table leting the list (and number of elements) available.

I would try:
composite index on AB (a, b)
extended stats on the 2 indexed columns
BEGIN
  DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS( 'schema_owner','AB',
  METHOD_OPT => 'FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE SKEWONLY ' ||
                'FOR COLUMNS SIZE SKEWONLY (A,B)' );
END;

And the query:
with subtable_b(id) as (
    select id from b where ...
)
select ab.a 
from ab
join subtable_b sb on ab.b = sb.id 
group by ab.a having 
    count(ab.b) = (select count(*) from subtable_b)
;

Then compare with composite index AB(b, a) (and adjusted stats).
